# Redis data resets to default on application restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I instantiated Redis in an initializer as:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")

KEYS = %w(
    first_attempt_success
    first_attempt_failure
    first_retry_success
    first_retry_failure
  )

  unless $stats
    $stats = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
    KEYS.map { |k| $stats.set(k, 0) }
  end
```

and I then went ahead to use it in my model as follow:

```
class StatsCounter

  KEYS = %w(
    first_attempt_success
    first_attempt_failure
    first_retry_success
    first_retry_failure
  )

  def self.stats
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
    unless $stats
      $stats = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
      KEYS.map { |k| $stats.set(k, 0) }
    end
    $stats
  end

  def self.get_stats
    Hash[KEYS.collect { |k| [k, stats.get(k)] }]
  end
end
```

But the problem I am having is that each time I restart my server - (restart the app), all saved data in my Redis instance resets to zero. 
I understand that Redis is an in-memory database.
How do I do it, so that my data persists, even when the application restarts? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I found what may be causing that, and also a fix for it.

By replacing this:

```
   KEYS.map { |k| $stats.set(k, 0) }
```

with a simple ternary that checks if the particular Redis key has already been set as follow:

```
KEYS.map { |k| $stats.get(k) ? true : $stats.set(k, 0) }
```

I was able to prevent my data from getting reset to the `0` default each time the application restarts.

Thanks to you all.